# Verify and decrypt signature generated with a pvk.key and BouncyCastle crypto apis

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, bouncycastle, public-key

I have an applet that uses a "foo.key" file and a string password to generate a privateKey object, using BouncyCastle apis. Then a signature is created using this privateKey object and a string such as "MYNAMEHERE". All I know is that the algorythm used to generate this signature is RSA.

What I want to do is to decrypt (or verify) this signature in PHP. I have both files publicKey (file.cer) and privateKey (file.key) that where used to generate the privateKey object in Java.

Im trying using the openssl_verify functions in PHP, passing the values:
openssl_verify("MYNAMEHERE", $signature, "file.cer"), where $signature contains the String representation of the signature object generated in Java: new String (signature).

I dont know if this process is correct to verify the signature, or what kind of encoding/decoding process i have to do before using this function.

I hope somebody points me the right direction!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 for getting bouncy castle into the title...

Comment: @DigitalPrecision that's not a very constructive comment, try without sarcasm

Comment: this question is lacking detail, try and give as much information as possible

Comment: @owlstead: Was just a joke man, relax.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough information, such as the actual signature or how it is encoded. Normally RSA means RSA in PKCS#1 1.5 mode using SHA-1 (Google it) which is more or less the default signature generation/verification algorithm in use today. In that case, the verify should proceed as you've described. The password is not needed anymore, it might just be used to decrypt the private key. You can still use the private key to see if an sign in PHP/openssl does create the same data. If not, a different hash or PKCS#1 v2.1 signature may have been used.

Comment: Thanks for replying @owlstead
After trying some different functions in PHP I got stucked in that area so I opted for doing the verification in Java too, but still, I have problems to find out how the signature was created (since it wasnt me who generated the keys). I have both files, .key and .cer. What would be the best approach to sign a simple string like: "HELLOWORLD" with the privateKey and then verifiy it with the .cer file??

I hope u can help me again, thanks in advance!